# Error on Activities related list when Restriction Rule is applied

Tags: activities, restrictionrules

I am encountering issues in activities related list when I applied a restriction rule, user is able to able to open the activities but the related list keeps throwing the error, tried removing the restriction rule and it works normally.
[image]

Comment: Based on salesforce backend logs, the stacktrace Id (780117825) points to `Exception while parsing obligations: <match><arg1>RecordType.Name</arg1><arg2>FeedbackCall</arg2></match>`  Here FeedbackCall is org specific parameter. If you need specific details for your org please do a fresh repro and share the timestamp along with timezone so I can check backend log again

Comment: Thats the criteria we used on the restriction rule (based on record type). As a workaround, we tried using custom field on the restriction and no longer seeing the above error. We are still observing the behavior as sometimes the error show sometimes not. Will further update you on this matter if the error still persist. Thank you for your response, much appreciated